# Replying to an Email Alert from a Discussion Board List

Tags: alert, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to get a definitive answer to a question about list alerts.  When I setup an alert on a SP 2010 discussion board list, I can create a list item and receive the alert.  But when I reply to the email, I would expect that my reply would show under the initial thread...but it doesn't.  I've done research that shows that it can be done out-of-the-box by setting the email address up in Central Admin, but I can't do this for then entire farm.  Can anyone shed some light on this functionality (can it be done or not)?

Answer (score 1):

The farm can be configured to handle incoming email, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx.  Once it's configured in the farm, then the incoming email settings can be configured on the discussion list.  At that point, the discussion list will receive email messages sent to the discussion list email address.